# Bad network performance on KVM guest

Tags: centos, debian, kvm-virtualization

I have a dedicated server connected to a 1000 Mbit port. However, the Debian guest is only getting half to a 1/4 the speeds:

On the node itself (Linux node 2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 25 21:43:11 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux):

```
wget http://www.bbned.nl/scripts/speedtest/download/file1000mb.bin -O /dev/null
--2012-11-11 23:10:11--  http://www.bbned.nl/scripts/speedtest/download/file1000mb.bin
Resolving www.bbned.nl... 62.177.144.181
Connecting to www.bbned.nl|62.177.144.181|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1048576000 (1000M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: â/dev/nullâ

100%[====================================>] 1,048,576,000  100M/s   in 10s

2012-11-11 23:10:21 (100 MB/s) - â/dev/nullâ
```

On the guest (Debian 6.0.5, x64: Linux debian 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 10:07:46 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux):

```
wget http://www.bbned.nl/scripts/speedtest/download/file1000mb.bin -O /dev/null
--2012-11-11 23:10:41--  http://www.bbned.nl/scripts/speedtest/download/file1000mb.bin
Resolving www.bbned.nl... 62.177.144.181
Connecting to www.bbned.nl|62.177.144.181|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1048576000 (1000M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: â/dev/nullâ

100%[=================================================================================================================================================================================================>] 1,048,576,000 16.5M/s   in 42s

2012-11-11 23:11:23 (23.8 MB/s) - â/dev/nullâ
```

I use the **virtio** NIC. I tried some more NICs: e1000 and the Realtek 8139 but those yield even worse results.

Anyone has an idea how to improve these speeds?

Comment: Oops, when I saw your question I figuring it out as an easy one : "use virtio" - it's supposed to be the smartest driver out there.

Comment: Why are you using a kvm guest ? Why not openvz or another type of container ? Just noticed your kernel versions matched.

Comment: @ErwanQueffélec I need to run more operating systems than Linux.

Comment: What's the setup otherwise?  Is the VM bridging to the same NIC in use for the host, is there a separate NIC or are you using NAT?  Any firewall rules or QoS setup?

Comment: @rnxrx there's a seperate NIC, called `br0`. `eth0` doesn't bridge to it.

Comment: br0 is a bridge port... try 'brctl show br0' to see what it's connecting to.  It's likely something like virbr0 and eth0 (or should be).

Comment: @rnxrx It gives me the following output: http://pasteit.cc/704

Comment: So br0 is bridged to eth0.  Can you ping from the guest IP to the default gateway on the subnet?  Do you see any packet loss?  Try copying some files from the host IP to the guest to isolate the issue.  BTW - Stick with the virtio drivers - they're much better.

Comment: @rnxrx I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been fixed with:

```
service iptables stop
echo > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
service iptables start
```

It seems there were some mangle iptable rules.

Comment: In the host or the guest? What was the actual problem?

Comment: @MichaelHampton On the host. iptables are used for bandwidth counting. Somehow it was messed up.